Excel Chart: select data label by its name
How do you select a chart data label by its name?
This code by BigBen uses .Caption to select a certain label and rename it:
Loop through chart and altering labels (Category Name)
Sub ShortenLabels()
    Dim k As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveChart
        For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
                With .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel
                    .Caption = Replace(.Caption, "AAAA", "AA")
                    .Caption = Replace(.Caption, "BBBB", "BB")
                    .Caption = Replace(.Caption, "CCCC", "CC")
                End With
            Next j
        Next k
    End With
End Sub

How do you say, "with label with .Caption = "AA", e.g. change font color?
Sub FormatLabelWithCertainCaption()
    Dim k As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveChart
        For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
                With .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel
                    With .Caption = "AA"
                        ' change font color
                    End With
                End With
            Next j
        Next k
    End With
End Sub

This works, but you need to enter the point number in the code:
With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(6).DataLabel
    With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    End With
End With

UPDATE
With If .Caption = "AA" Then nothing happens:
Sub FormatLabelWithCertainCaption_v2()
    Dim k As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveChart
        For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
                With .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel
                    If .Caption = "AA" Then                      
                        .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters. _
                            Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                    End If
                End With
            Next j
        Next k
    End With
End Sub


If .Caption = "AA" Then

Please have a look at the update. Nothing happens, when running the macro. I must be missing something.

Did your code hit the Format line?  If not then there's no label with that caption.

Stepping though each line, it jumps from 'If..Then' to 'End If'

BigBen's code works fine, though – which wouldn't, if the label had no caption, no?

If you stepped through each line and it never gets to the ".format" line then the if condition is always false. I would suggest you dump the contents of the ".Caption" to see what it contains.

@Skypilot65 I don't understand. How do I dump the contents? What does that mean? And how come the very first code does work? I'm using the same caption running these tests.

Just tested it again: the first code by BigBen works fine. It finds the label with the caption "AA" and changes its name to "BB". This means, the label has a caption and BigBen's code does find it, no? It wouldn't work otherwise, no?

The first block of code replaces "AAAA" with "AA".  It doesn't find "AA".  Add Debug.Print .Caption inside the loop and check the output.

@TimWilliams Added Debug.Print.Caption. The immediate window shows a list of all data labels. Every label has: 1. category 2. value 3. percentage. "AA" is on the list.

This is the code I use to add labels to a chart: "Excel Chart: color data labels by categories" link

"AA" is the complete value of the caption?  Or does it only contain "AA"?  You're using = so you're looking for an exact match....

"AA" is the category name of one of the labels. the immediate window shows: first line=category: AA, second line=value: 10,00, third line=percentage: 1,73%

How would you say "If Caption = category+value+percentage"? If .Caption = "AA  10,00 1,73%" Then does not work. I tried to separate with "," and ";" and "+"

Try If .Caption = "AA" & vbLf & "10,00" & vbLf & "1,73%" Then . The 2nd number may be surrounded by spaces. If it doesn't work, please share a screenshot of your chart.

It works. If .Caption = "AA" & vbLf & " 10,00   " & vbLf & "1,73%" Then does the job. Note: the 2nd number is indeed surrounded by spaces. 1x space at the beginning, 3x space at the end. You can use the immediate window to count/see them, just step through the caption.

If you only care about the "AA" part you can use If .Caption Like "AA" & vblf & "*" Then

If .Caption Like "AA" & vblf & "*" Then with "AA" being the category allows you to say "if a label has the category "AA", then e.g. change font color". This is a neat way to work with labels of a certain category.
